# Header is duplicating REACT routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue where using the  function in my REACT routing, it seems to be duplicating my whole header.

How can I stop my header being duplicated?

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css';
import {Outlet, Link} from "react-router-dom"


const Header = () => {

   return (
      <div><nav>
         <div class="menu-icon">
            <span class="fas fa-bars"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="logo">
            Home
         </div>
         <div class="cancel-icon">
            <span class="fas fa-times"></span>
         </div>
         <form action="#">
            <div><input type="search" class="search-data" placeholder="Search" required /> </div></form>
         <div class="nav-items">
            <li>              
               <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>              
               <Link to="/Login">Login</Link>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
         </div>
      </nav>

      <Outlet />
      </div>


   )
}


export default Header;
```

[Duplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuEMR.png)

Comment: Add the code where you are using header component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.